# how to resolve component link in in entity

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

we are creating a schema with a component link and component link is using same schema. now while reading the component in EntityController we are not getting the component link data.

[image]

**Model Class code**

```
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @SemanticEntity(entityName = "Instructions", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "in")
    public class Instructions extends AbstractEntityModel {
        @SemanticProperty("in:SubTitle")
        @JsonProperty("SubTitle")
        private String subTitle;
        
        @SemanticProperty("in:Title")
        @JsonProperty("Title")
        private String title;
        
        @SemanticProperty("in:PDFFile")
        @JsonProperty("PDFFile")
        private BinaryItem pdfFile;
        
        @SemanticProperty("in:ChildInstructions")
        @JsonProperty("ChildInstructions")
        private List<Instructions> childInstructions;
    }
```

**Entity Controller code**

```
} else if(model != null && model instanceof Instructions) {
        Instructions tempModel = (Instructions)model;
        return tempModel;
    }
```

**JSON Preview from CME**

```
{
   "Id":"133089-133108",
   "Namespace":"tcm",
   "ComponentTemplate":{
      "Id":"133108",
      "Namespace":"tcm",
      "Title":"Instructions Details",
      "RevisionDate":"2022-01-13T11:24:02",
      "OutputFormat":"HTML Fragment",
      "Metadata":{
         "controller":"Generic:Generic",
         "view":"Generic:InstructionDetails",
         "regionView":"Generic:WebInstructionLinks"
      }
   },
   "Folder":{
      "Id":"17456",
      "Title":"001 First Law"
   },
   "Content":{
      "SubTitle":"First: The Law:",
      "Title":"Summary of the Provisions of Chapter Three of the Law No. 32 of 1968 concerning Currency, the Central Bank of Kuwait and the Organisation of Banking Business, and other Ministerial Resolutions and Related Provisions.",
      "PDFFile":{
         "$type":"EntityModelData",
         "Id":"2749",
         "Namespace":"tcm",
         "ComponentTemplate":{
            "Id":"126337",
            "Namespace":"tcm",
            "RevisionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
         },
         "Folder":{
            "Id":"1003",
            "Title":"CBK Instructions to Conventional Banks"
         },
         "BinaryContent":{
            "Url":"/Preview/en/images/instructions-issued-in-connection-with-the-organization-of-local-banks-investment-policy-2749_v30_tcm10-2749.pdf",
            "FileName":"instructions-issued-in-connection-with-the-organization-of-local-banks-investment-policy-2749_v30.pdf",
            "FileSize":159808,
            "MimeType":"application/pdf"
         },
         "SchemaId":"25"
      },
      "Style":"Bullet point Link",
      "ChildInstructions":{
         "$type":"EntityModelData",
         "Id":"133090",
         "Namespace":"tcm",
         "ComponentTemplate":{
            "Id":"126337",
            "Namespace":"tcm",
            "RevisionDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
         },
         "Folder":{
            "Id":"17456",
            "Title":"001 First Law"
         },
         "Content":{
            "Title":"Center of Risks System and Regulations Issued for its Implementation",
            "PDFFile":{
               "$type":"EntityModelData",
               "Id":"2732",
               "Namespace":"tcm"
            },
            "Style":"Bullet point Link",
            "ChildInstructions":{
               "$type":"EntityModelData",
               "Id":"133128",
               "Namespace":"tcm"
            }
         },
         "Metadata":{
            "childInstructionIds":"133128",
            "lastModifiedDate":"2022-01-19T10:15:44.3098017"
         },
         "SchemaId":"133088"
      }
   },
   "MvcData":{
      "ControllerName":"Generic",
      "ControllerAreaName":"Generic",
      "ViewName":"InstructionDetails",
      "AreaName":"Generic"
   },
   "XpmMetadata":{
      "ComponentID":"tcm:10-133089",
      "ComponentModified":"2022-01-19T10:15:30",
      "ComponentTemplateID":"tcm:10-133108-32",
      "ComponentTemplateModified":"2022-01-13T11:24:02",
      "IsRepositoryPublished":true
   },
   "Metadata":{
      "childInstructionIds":"133090",
      "lastModifiedDate":"2022-01-19T10:15:30.0532647"
   },
   "SchemaId":"133088"
}
```

**Error in log**

```
ERROR c.s.w.c.i.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl - Exception while getting field data for: private java.util.List com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.Instructions.childInstructions
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.exceptions.FieldConverterException: Cannot convert a entity model 133090 to class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.Instructions for semantic field ChildInstructions
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:43)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:17)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:65)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:135)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:126)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:693)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:673)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createViewModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:157)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:123)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:86)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:73)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:360)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.lambda$createRegionModel$10(DefaultModelBuilder.java:342)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createRegionModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:345)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.lambda$buildPageModel$8(DefaultModelBuilder.java:266)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildPageModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:59)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider._loadPage(DefaultContentProvider.java:104)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultContentProvider.getPageModel(DefaultContentProvider.java:175)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:290)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:119)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.controller.GenericPageController.handleGetPage(GenericPageController.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:479)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Exception happened while creating a entity model from: EntityModelData(id=133090, componentTemplate=ComponentTemplateData(id=126337, title=null, revisionDate=0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, outputFormat=null, metadata=null), linkUrl=, content={Title=Center of Risks System and Regulations Issued for its Implementation, PDFFile=EntityModelData(id=2732, componentTemplate=null, linkUrl=, content=null, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null), Style=Bullet point Link}, binaryContent=null, externalContent=null)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:133)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:86)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.EntityModelDataConverter.convert(EntityModelDataConverter.java:37)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException: Cannot get a view model tpe because of semantic mapping exception
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:109)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.getMappedModelTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:107)
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.mapping.semantic.SemanticMappingException: Ambiguous semantic mapping for http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:Instructions, found these mappings: [class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.Instructions, class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.Instructions]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.getEntityClassByFullyQualifiedName(SemanticMappingRegistryImpl.java:334)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.model.ViewModelRegistryImpl.getMappedModelTypes(ViewModelRegistryImpl.java:107)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Comment: In the CME preview the page R2 JSON output and update in your question for review.

Comment: @Velmurugan I have updated the question with the JSON output from CME preview.

Comment: if you just want only the component link data then you can use it in your model **private List<Link> childInstructions;**  this will get your link information. the component link will be resolved in the graphical side by model extension by default.

Comment: The error message shows  **Ambiguous semantic mapping for class com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.model.Instructions** double-check this one.

Comment: @Velmurugan Both Instructions components are based on the Instructions schema and childInstructions are multi-value component link field based on the same Instructions schema. I am not sure why it is throwing the Ambiguous semantic mapping exception.

Comment: The ambiguous semantic mapping error may stem from the fact that your `Instructions` class has a `SemanticEntity` annotation which mimics the default semantics (entityName = class name in SDL_CORE vocabulary).  Try removing that `SemanticEntity` annotation altogether; if the default semantics are okay for you, you don't need this annotation.

Comment: when i removed the SemanticEntity from the model class, i am getting values in simple field variables (like String and int) but i am not getting values in complex class field(like instructions)

Comment: @RickPannekoek please advice.

Comment: Did you also remove the prefixes from the `SemanticProperty` annotations?